# How to pass xkb options to ibus (and use them with m17n engines)?

Tags: input-languages, xkb

I am using ibus for input in different languages (mostly I use English and Russian, but also sometimes also Esperanto, Ukrainian, Greek, German, French etc). For English I use the `xkb:us::eng` engine which is essentially the basic xkb table for English. However I can't find any way as to how to use xkb options inside ibus. When the xkb engine is one, `setxkbmap -query` gives the following output:

```
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us
options:    compose:menu,grp:caps_toggle
```

But I'd prefer to have other set of options. For one, I don't need `grp:caps_toggle` at all, as I disabled and remapped the capslock key in `~/.Xmodmap` Plus I'd like to have typographical symbols, lv3 switch by Alt_R and other handy things from `setxkbmap`. Before ibus I used uim with the us keyboard and I had the following in my startup file:

```
setxkbmap "us" -option "compose:menu,lv3:ralt_switch,grp_led:scroll,misc:typo,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
```

uim used its engines on top of xkb, so all those options worked in both in direct mode and in any engine, at least ones from m17n. Ibus, on the other hand, uses xkb as one of its engines, so calling `setxkbmap` seems to break everything. How do I pass options to xkb engines inside ibus? Is it even possible?

Additional question: how do I use the same xkb options for m17n engines? In ibus GUI there is a preferences tab for m17n engines, but it only has a "Use US keyboard layout" checkmark without any way to specify which exactly xkb layout is to be used and with which options. I use `m17n:ru:kbd` engine (rather than xkb one) for Russian, but I'd like to have all the handy options from xkb when I use it. Same for all the other languages/engines I occasionally use.

Answer (score 0):

I managed a workaround by getting rid of Ibus' proper engine switch mechanism entirely and instead using `sh` scripting. I made a script called `switchim.sh` and put it into `~/keyboard/` directory. With it I pass `setxkbmap` options each time I switch the layout. As I want to switch from English into Russian and from anything else into English, it looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $(ibus engine) == xkb:us::eng ]; then
    ibus engine m17n:ru:kbd
    setxkbmap -option "compose:menu,lv3:ralt_switch,grp_led:scroll,misc:typo,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
else
    ibus engine xkb:us::eng
    setxkbmap -option "compose:menu,lv3:ralt_switch,grp_led:scroll,misc:typo,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
fi
```

I then bound this script with my DE (which is XFCE) hotkey function to my "Next group" key, that is, Caps Lock. I also made similar scripts for switching into other languages, like this one for Esperanto:

```
#!/bin/bash
ibus engine m17n:eo:x-sistemo
setxkbmap -option "compose:menu,lv3:ralt_switch,grp_led:scroll,misc:typo,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
```

Those scripts I bound to Super+*letter* keys.

This works, more or less. Compose key still only works in English, but everything else seems to work decently enough. It's a dirty hack, but has to do for now.